# Set textView to Bottom Right

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to fix two text views to the bottom right and keep it above the listview.
If the listview is empty i want it fixed to the bottom right but with this code if i add some items to the listview the textview disappears. 
[Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bFP0.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="Fechar Comanda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnFecharComanda" />
        <Button
            android:text="Extrato"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnExtrato" />
        <Button
            android:text="Enviar Cozinha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnEnviarCozinha" />
        <Button
            android:text="Anterior"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnAnterior" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/sportsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/primeira"
            android:layout_weight="33" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/sportsList_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/segunda"
            android:layout_weight="34" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:id="@+id/linearLay123123"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/sportsList_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/terceira" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/odkjfs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:gravity="bottom">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="R$15"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've tagged your question with `ReleativeLayout`, which is what the solution to your problem is. You need to change your `linearLay123123` to a `RelativeLayout` and tell the layout system, that you always want `odkjfs` at the bottom right and your `ListView` `sportsList_2` above it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="Fechar Comanda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnFecharComanda" />
        <Button
            android:text="Extrato"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnExtrato" />
        <Button
            android:text="Enviar Cozinha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnEnviarCozinha" />
        <Button
            android:text="Anterior"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnAnterior" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/sportsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/primeira"
            android:layout_weight="33" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/sportsList_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/segunda"
            android:layout_weight="34" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:id="@+id/linearLay123123"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/sportsList_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/odkjfs"
                android:entries="@array/terceira" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/odkjfs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="R$15"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You Id's are very hard to remember so I advise you to change them.

But lets break down the layout above. You have an outer layout with two rows. The bottom one has three columns. What you wanted to change is rightmost column so that it persists something on the bottom of it.

So the easiest thing to do here is to change from a `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`, since it is much easier to align views relative to each other in it, as the name indicates.

So after changing it to `RelativeLayout` we need to tell the `ListView` to align to the top. And that it needs to adjust its height to be above the content below.

```xml
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/odkjfs"
```

Then on the `LinearLayout` which you wanted to be on bottom right. We need to tell it to adjust right, and adjust to bottom:

```xml
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Simple as that.